# How to dump on Route api doesn't work Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, dump

I gonna tried to make a query on project Laravel with VueJs on front.

When i try to dump my variable, nothing nothing is happening.

I have this road on api.php:

```
Route::resource('users.options', OptionController::class)->only('index', 'show', 'update', 'store', 'destroy');
```

And it's my controller :

```
$options = Option::with([
            'status',
            'lot:id,number,price',
            'promoteur:id,name',
            'programme:id,name,id_city',
            'programme.city:id,name,zip_code'
        ])
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->select("id", "id_user", "id_prospect", "id_option_status", "id_promoteur", "id_programme", 'id_lot', "prospect_firstname", "prospect_lastname", 'created_at', 'commission_amount_iad', 'commission_rate_iad')
        ->get();

dd($options);
```

when I go to the page where the data is normally displayed, nothing....

I specify that the query is good, it works, I just want to have the dd of this one. The questions is How to Dump on the route api.php

Thanks for help !

Comment: you cannot use dd to display response in api.php because it does not render any html, so you have to use print_r() to echo output inside api.php.

Comment: are you sure that this route works?

Comment: Thanks for answer.
So i use print_r($options) in api.php ? Where display the print_r result ? on my page web or ... ?

Comment: You can check it using postman or in network tab of browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your endpoint is on api.php, in vue you should point to:

```
https://www.url.com/api/users.options
```

Suggestion: change users.options to users/options

In your terminal, clean cache for routes after change routes (web or api):

```
php artisan route:clear
```

- Go to your browser, open console (mouse right click, then Inspect.
- Go to tab Network Click on your page, to call that endpoint
- Search in Network if endpoint was called Click that row.
- Now you can see what request was made, what payload was sent and what is the endpoint response.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
I don't know why you want i change this route. The route works, i have the date, i just wanna dd this.

Comment: The change of route was just a suggestion. The rest of the answer allow you to see data.

Comment: Oh yes ;) 
it's ok i can see dd($options) on console, Network, thanks you

Comment: Usually, on those tests, we need to reply the click multiple times until reach our solution. In that case you, at network tab, you can click with right button on the call, and choose Reply Xhr. you're welcome :)

Answer (score -1):

You can print using print_r($options); exit; so it stop the execution and print collection object.

Comment: Thanks for you'r answer but  print_r($options); exit; doesn't work

Comment: fyi, in Laravel you could just `dd($options);` - which OP already has in their code